# android - xml. Having difficulty lining up the elements in the way I'd like

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'd like to center these phrases in my view. I can get "@+id/m_popcorn" to the center of the screen but, I cannot get"@+id/m_keyhole" and the other text views to line up beneath it. I would also like all five phrases to be centered in the screen, rather than having only "@+id/m_popcorn" centered. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scaleType="center" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/viola_desmond_pic"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:src="@drawable/viola_desmond" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#AA000000"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc" >

</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/m_popcorn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="spilled popcorn" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/m_keyhole"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/m_popcorn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="keyhole" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/m_pistol"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/m_keyhole"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="pistol" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/m_cat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/m_pistol"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="cat" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/m_pen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/m_cat"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="pen" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it would be more appropriate if you attach both screenshots too, (current and desired layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the layout file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/viola_desmond_pic"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="testing"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#AA000000"
        android:contentDescription="text description"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/m_popcorn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="spilled popcorn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/m_keyhole"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="keyhole" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/m_pistol"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="pistol" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/m_cat"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="cat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/m_pen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="pen" />
  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Also you can remove image view and set the image is background for linear layout if the purpose is to draw image in the background...

Comment: Thanks for the help and example, pitnal.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to have a list of textView in center of your layout, i am using a linear layout that fill the parent layout and set it's gravity to center, any child of this layout is in the center of it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="center">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <TextView
            android:contentDescription="desk"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:id="@+id/list_background"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#AA000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/m_popcorn"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="spilled popcorn"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/m_keyhole"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="keyhole"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/m_pistol"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="pistol"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/m_cat"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="cat"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/m_pen"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="pen"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="desk"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viola_desmond_pic"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```